Identically distributed then conditionally identically distributed
This seems really easy, but I can't exactly formulate it.

Let $X$, $Y_1$, $Y_2$ all be identically distributed, but $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are dependent. I want to know whether the conditional distribution of $Y_1|X=1$ and $Y_2|X=1$ are also identical or not.

I don't think they should be identical. For example, let $X, Y_1, Y_2$ take values 1, 2, 3 with equal probability. Let $Y_1=X$ and $Y_2=4-X$. Then $Y_1|X=1$ is 1 with probability 1, but $Y_2|X=1$ is 3 with probability 1. Hence they are not the identically distributed. Am I correct, or is there a flaw in the argument?
EDIT) I want to find a counterexample for the above case where X is not uniform. In my particular case, I am given X with $P(X=i) = \frac{1}{2}P(X=i+1)$ on the set $\{0, 1, \cdots, n-1\}$. I want to find $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ identically distributed so that when conditioned on $X=i$, then $Y_1|X=i$ and $Y_2|X=i$ are not identically distributed.

You are correct. No flaw whatsoever.

@geetha290krm Thank you for answering. May I ask if there is a counterexample when $X$ is not uniform?

Take $Y_1=X$ so that $Y_1|X=1$ is just $1$. If $Y_2$ is independent of $X$ then $Y_2|X=1$ has the distrbution of $X, Y_1,Y_2$, which can be anything!.

@geetha290krm Ahh I see. Thank you!
